# Multiple attacks

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multiattack

If a feat or power gives you two attacks, is that two attacks per BAB, or is is two attacks total?

Here is the power that prompted this question: [Lesser Beast Totem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/beast-totem-lesser-su)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different categories of weapon: manufactured and natural.

Manufactured weapons are the usual case for players. Every creature capable of wielding a manufactured weapon may make a single attack with that weapon as a standard action. Such creatures with high BAB (+6 or greater) can also choose to attack multiple times as a full-round action, where each successive attack has a cumulative −5 penalty (e.g. BAB +11 means you get three attacks, one at +11, another at +6, and a final attack at +1).

Natural weapons are granted to more powerful creatures or as class features, such as the Lesser Beast Totem, and follow different rules. As a standard action, a creature may attack once with a single natural weapon; this is similar to how manufactured weapons work. However, natural weapons do not get iteratives like manufactured weapons. Instead, as a full-round action, a creature with multiple natural weapons may attack once with each one.

Some natural weapons are “secondary,” and attack at a −5 attack bonus (and only add ½ Str to damage); when multiple natural weapons are used as a full-round action, one weapon (or, sometimes, one pair of natural weapons) must be chosen to be the primary weapon; any additional weapons are treated as secondary even if they would usually be primary.

So for the Lesser Beast Totem, the pair of Claws would be primary, so a full-round action to attack would allow one attack with each claw, both attacks at full BAB and adding full Str to damage. Even at high BAB, however, you would not be able to attack more than once with each Claw.

Finally, you can combine the two: as a full-round action, you may attack with a manufactured weapon, getting all iteratives as normal, and then *also* attack once with each natural weapon, though they are always secondary when used with a manufactured weapon (the manufactured weapon is effectively the primary weapon). However, you may not attack with any natural weapons that are being used to wield the manufactured weapon. For example, if your barbarian with Lesser Beast Totem wields a longsword in one hand, and attacks with it, he could also attack with the other Claw attack, but not the claws on the hand holding the longsword.